# SQL SUM some COUNTS

Tags: sql, aggregates

If I have a table like this:

```
FRUIT
------------------------
GRANNY SMITH
BANNANA
CHERRY
RED DELICIOUS
DURIAN
FIG
GRAPE
LIME
ORANGE
BRAEBURN
TANGERINE
GRANNY SMITH
ORANGE
ORANGE
GRANNY SMITH
LIME
FIG
FIG
GRANNY SMITH
BRAEBURN
```

And I want to produce the following output using SQL, how do I do it?  I want to sum the count of the different apple varieties under apple, and the same for citrus types, but everything else is just a count.

```
FRUIT       COUNT
----------- ------
APPLE       7
BANNANA     1
CHERRY      1
CITRUS      6
DURIAN      1
FIG         3
GRAPE       1
```

I tried using a nested aggregate with conditionals but nested aggregates aren't supported in SQL so I'm looking for some other ideas.

Comment: How would your DB know that Breaburn is an apple?

Comment: Do you have another table that defines whether something is an apple or citrus?  At a minimum,you should include this information in your question.

Comment: @HannoBinder, Gordon, I was using CASE to group varieties of apples as apples

Comment: @Chuck Add a type in your table as column and maintain a reference table for type to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can GROUP BY your existing CASE statement, but you must use a Derived Table (or repeat that huge CASE in GROUP BY):

```
select FRUIT, COUNT(*)
from 
 (
   select CASE 
             WHEN FRUIT IN ('GRANNY SMITH', 'RED DELICIOUS', ...) THEN 'APPLE'
             WHEN FRUIT IN ('ORANGE', 'TANGERINE', ...) THEN 'CITRUS'
             ELSE FRUIT
          END AS FRUIT
   from tab
 ) dt
group by FRUIT
order by FRUIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a FruitCategory column to your table.

```
Fruit          FruitCategory
----------------------------
GRANNY SMITH   APPLE
BANNANA        BANNANA
BRAEBURN       APPLE
...
```

Then you can group by FruitCategory

```
SELECT FruitCategory, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM tblFruit
GROUP BY FruitCategory
ORDER BY FruitCategory
```

---

But it is better to have a separate fruit category table.

```
FruitCategoryID FruitCategory
-----------------------------
1               Apple
2               Banana
...
```

Then change your Fruit table to

```
Fruit          FruitCategoryID
------------------------------
GRANNY SMITH   1
BANNANA        2
BRAEBURN       1
...
```

This allows you to use the category table as lookup for combo boxes etc. and makes it more robust, as writing the category names directly into fruit table is error prone.

```
SELECT
    c.FruitCategory, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
    tblFruit f
    INNER JOIN tblFruitCategory c
        ON f.FruitCategoryID = c.FruitCategoryID
GROUP BY
    f.FruitCategoryID
ORDER BY
    c.FruitCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you added Apples as `type=1`, Citrus fruits as `type=2` and others as `type=3` in the same table (with column as `Type`), then just do this -

```
select CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN APPLE ELSE CITRUS, count(*) as COUNT
from table
where Type in (1,2)
group by Type
union all
select FRUIT, count(*) as COUNT
from table
where Type = 3
group by FRUIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  You could also make FRUIT_LOOKUP a table, but you don't need to, you can make it virtually in your query like this:

```
WITH FRUIT_LOOKUP AS
(
   SELECT 'GRANNY SMITH' AS FRUIT, 'APPLE' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BANNANA' AS FRUIT, 'BANNANA' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'CHERRY' AS FRUIT, 'CHERRY' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'RED DELICIOUS' AS FRUIT, 'APPLE' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DURIAN' AS FRUIT, 'DURIAN' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'FIG' AS FRUIT, 'FIG' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'GRAPE' AS FRUIT, 'GRAPE' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'LIME' AS FRUIT, 'CITRUS' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'TANGERINE' AS FRUIT, 'CITRUS' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BRAEBURN' AS FRUIT, 'APPLE' AS FTYPE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ORANGE' AS FRUIT, 'CITRUS' AS FTYPE
)
SELECT FL.FTYPE AS FRUIT, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM FRUITTABLE F
JOIN FRUIT_LOOKUP FL ON F.FRUIT = FL.FRUIT
GROUP BY FL.FTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Select FRUIT,Count(FRUIT) from DBTable Group By FRUIT

and if you want to ordered :)

Select FRUIT,Count(FRUIT) from DBTable Group By FRUIT Order by Count(FRUIT)

Comment: He wants different apple varieties (Braeburn, Granny Smith. etc.) to appear as APPLE in the result.